# How to read column names including the crossbar by using read.delim in R

Tags: r, crossbar

I have a .txt file.

The colnames were including the crossbar (-). if i use the read.delim or read.table, the crossbar(-) will be changed into dot (.).

for example
I use the read.table function for the txt as following.

```
    a-10    A10 a11
1   570713.1532 4347.127038 560074.5148
2   361794.0426 4365.151908 271537.033
3   400072.0642 4448.913543 278229.5815
4   1413702.462 1961060.359 1290639.429
5   1825921.357 917867.7933 1744369.165
6   1392255.25  3239883.128 497342.8758
7   404629.443  377138.1097 396159.1927
8   879366.5207 1002531.369 989364.4228
9   1736700.906 4226107.776 3281239.818




    X    a.10       A10             a11
1   1   570713.2    4347.127    560074.5
2   2   361794.0    4365.152    271537.0
3   3   400072.1    4448.914    278229.6
4   4   1413702.5   1961060.359 1290639.4
5   5   1825921.4   917867.793  1744369.2
6   6   1392255.2   3239883.128 497342.9
7   7   404629.4    377138.110  396159.2
8   8   879366.5    1002531.369 989364.4
9   9   1736700.9   4226107.776 3281239.8
```

I hope to keep the crossbar, but not the dot. Can anyone give helps and tell me how to read the table?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post first few rows of the txt file ?

Comment: Hi Ronak, the rows was shown. Thanks

Comment: You can use the `check.names` argument in `read.table()` (and related functions), e.g. `read.table(file, header = TRUE, check.names = FALSE)`.  Be aware that doing this might cause headaches down the road.

Comment: wow, thanks H 1, it works!